# Undefined is not a function : Instantiating Backbone collection

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, handlebars.js

Just getting my feet wet with Backbone but I am having some trouble getting this simple example working. I get an error

> "Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function "

when I try to instantiate States collection `var States = new States();`. The model/collection is already declared so I am baffled.

```
 <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/wycats/handlebars.js/handlebars-1.0.rc.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"  src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.5.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
        <script  type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.0.0/backbone-min.js"></script>

        <div id='StatesContainer' ></div>

        <!-- 
            Note the []  this is important
        because handlebars and backbone collections
        dont play well with each other in regards
        to naming JSON groups 
        -->
        <script id="StateTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <div>
            {{#each []}}
                {{this.name}}
                {{this.abbreviation}}
                <br/>
            {{/each}}
        <div>
        </script>
        <!-- End templates setup -->

        <script>
            var State = Backbone.Model.extend({});
            var States = Backbone.Collection.extend({
                model: State,
                initialize: function () { }
            });
            //define view for all models
            var StatesView = Backbone.View.extend({
                render: function () {
                    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
                    var html = template(this.collection.toJSON());
                    $(this.el).html(html);
                },
                initialize: function () {
                    //wire up events to trigger re-rendering of view
                    this.collection.on('add', this.render, this);
                    this.collection.on('remove', this.render, this)
                }
            });
            //THANKS Rameş Aliyev for the feedback on making this cleaner
            // https://gist.github.com/4682984

            $(document).ready(function () {
                // We have to do this stuff in the dom ready
                // so that the container objects get built out
                // Create instance of model Collection
                var States = new States();

                // Create new instances of the person models
                var State = new State({ name: "New York", abbreviation: "NY" });
                var State2 = new State({ name: "New Jersey", abbreviation: "NJ" });
                var State3 = new State({ name: "New Mexico", abbreviation: "NM" });

                //add models to the collection
                States.add(State);
                States.add(State2);

                // Create instances of the views
                var StatesView = new StatesView({
                    collection: States
                });

                //container for rendered view
                StatesView.el = $('#StatesContainer');
                //template 
                StatesView.source = $('#StateTemplate').html();
                //render view
                StatesView.render();

                //StatesView.render();
                //add a new model to the collection, will update view
                //people.add(State3);

                //remove some models from the collection, will update view
                //people.remove(State2);
                //people.remove(State3);
            });
         </script>
        </body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```
var States = new States();
```

to

```
var states = new States();
```

Or use a different variable

States is a Backbone collection . You are getting a error because of the name collision.

Try using a different name for naming instances.

Use **PascalCase** for function names and `camelCase` for instances of the objects.

```
 var State = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var States = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: State,
    initialize: function () {}
});

//define view for all models
var StatesView = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function () {
        var template = Handlebars.compile($('#StateTemplate').html());
        var html = template(this.collection.toJSON());
        $(this.el).html(html);
    },
    initialize: function () {
        //wire up events to trigger re-rendering of view
        this.collection.on('add', this.render, this);
        this.collection.on('remove', this.render, this)
    }
});
//THANKS Rameş Aliyev for the feedback on making this cleaner
// https://gist.github.com/4682984

$(document).ready(function () {
    // We have to do this stuff in the dom ready
    // so that the container objects get built out
    // Create instance of model Collection
    var states = new States();

    // Create new instances of the person models
    var state = new State({
        name: "New York",
        abbreviation: "NY"
    });
    var state2 = new State({
        name: "New Jersey",
        abbreviation: "NJ"
    });
    var state3 = new State({
        name: "New Mexico",
        abbreviation: "NM"
    });

    //add models to the collection
    states.add(state);
    states.add(state2);

    // Create instances of the views
    var statesView = new StatesView({
        collection: states
    });

    //container for rendered view
    statesView.el = $('#StatesContainer');
    //template 
    statesView.source = $('#StateTemplate').html();
    //render view
    statesView.render();

});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/qEeAf/)**

Comment: Also, don't modify `el` after instantiating `statesView`; set it in the initializer object.